# How to root Xperia P device

Tags: rooting, sony-xperia-p

How do I get root access for my Xperia P device runing Jelly Bean(4.1)?

Is it required to unlock bootloader before trying to root the phone?

Comment: Can you tell your build number from settings

Comment: It's 6.2.A.1.100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay here is how to root  without unlocking bootloader for XP Jellybean. This is confirmed working and do it in your own risk.

**Note:** 
**Charge your phone to 100% before doing this and back up contact,message and any other installed app.**

1. Download and install [Flashtool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=920746) (If you dont know how to flash using flashtool follow this [tutorial](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2054486)
2. Download `Sony Xperia P_6.1.1.B.1.75_Generic World` from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-u/p-development/rom-sony-xperia-p6-1-1-b-1-75generic-t2089118)
3. Put the ftf file inside the firmware folder of flashtool
4. Turn `Usb Debugging on` in your phone
5. Shut down your Xperia P
6. Press the lightning icon inside flashtool
7. Select `FLASHMODE` (NOT FASTBOOT)
8. Choose the Sony Xperia P_6.1.1.B.1.75_Generic World ftf file for XP
9. When flashtool ask you to connect your device, insert USB cable first in your phone then hold `Volume Down` Button and insert the other end of USB in your PC
10. Wait till it finish
11. Disconnect your phone and power on. You are back in ICS
12. Flash [0.559 kernel](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=1665266&d=1358806560) via flashtool
13. Remove the phone from PC, reboot the phone
14. Connect the phone to PC
15. Open flashtool hit the root button
16. When you see "waiting for restore to finish" open your phone and run Backup&Restore app and restore RootMe.tar file.
17. Wait until Flashtool do the rest of work
18. When u r done flash [.75 kernel](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=1644206&d=1358172225) via flashtool reboot the phone
19. Download [CWM](http://kumquat-project.googlecode.com/files/cwm-1.0-nypon.zip)
20. Extract the folder
21. Connect your phone to the pc with USB debugging
22. Click on install.bat
23. Download [JB KERNEL](http://click.xda-developers.com/api/click?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_jsonp_139531307691619&key=f0a7f91912ae2b52e0700f73990eb321&loc=http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-u/p-development/tut-root-jb-locked-boot-loader-t2250101&v=1&libId=b05cf8bc-f6c2-406c-84eb-7d0f1f2e8be3&out=http://d-h.st/oBB&title=%5BTUT%5D%5BPRE-ROOTED%20JB%20ROM%20ZIP%5D%5BHow%20To%5D%20Root%20JB%20for%20locked%20Boot%20Loader%20-%20xda-developers&txt=http://d-h.st/oBB) and [PRE ROOTED JB](http://click.xda-developers.com/api/click?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_jsonp_139531311757320&key=f0a7f91912ae2b52e0700f73990eb321&loc=http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-u/p-development/tut-root-jb-locked-boot-loader-t2250101&v=1&libId=b05cf8bc-f6c2-406c-84eb-7d0f1f2e8be3&out=http://d-h.st/aze&title=%5BTUT%5D%5BPRE-ROOTED%20JB%20ROM%20ZIP%5D%5BHow%20To%5D%20Root%20JB%20for%20locked%20Boot%20Loader%20-%20xda-developers&txt=http://d-h.st/aze)
24. Put it on your SD card
25. Well Now shut down you Xperia P
26. Turn it on
27. Enter CWM Recovery by pressing volume down (dont hold the volume button put press repeatedly move up and down using volume button select using power button)
28. Mount System
29. Mount Data
30. Mount Cache
31. Flash the JB Kernel Zip
32. Again Mount System
33. Mount Data
34. Mount Cache
35. Flash the JB_prerooted_6.2.A.0.400.zip
36. Do Not Reboot !!
37. Wipe Data/Factory Reset
38. Reboot !!

It take some minutes, But just wait with patience

For the 1st time you may get FC from Thememanager and Timescape

Enjoy Rooted JB !!!

Source: [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-u/p-development/tut-root-jb-locked-boot-loader-t2250101)

Answer (score 1):

Rooting will involve several steps. You may or may not want to unlock your bootloader first (I did unlock it first before trying the following steps).

In order to use these instructions, you'll need a Windows computer and your device must be running Ice Cream Sandwich or Jelly Bean. You'll also want to ensure your device is charged before trying to root it.

These instructions are paraphrased from [Xperia HTC Rooting](http://xperiahtcrootingrom.com/root-sony-xperia-p-ics-jellybean/).

1. [Download the Bin4ry rooting software](http://www.mediafire.com/download/k7qu98huz3vxr7b/Root_with_Restore_by_Bin4ry_v31.zip), and extract it to your desktop
2. Enable USB debugging on your Xperia P. You can do this by going into Settings > Application > Developer options > USB debugging and checking the box to enable it.
3. Connect your Xperia P to your computer via a USB cable. If your device is not recognized, you may need to install the [Sony Xperia P USB driver](http://dl-developer.sonymobile.com/drivers/Xperia_P_Xperia_U_Xperia_sola_drivers.zip) first, then reconnect it again.
4. Double click on `RunMe.bat` file in the Bin4ry folder that you extracted
5. A black command window popup should appear with green text. Type 1 to select New_standard_root and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
6. Follow the on screen instructions to root your device.

Note: If the New_Stand_Root method does not work, try repeating steps 4 and 5 with the second root method (New Xperia Root by Goroh_kun).

Comment: I think it wont work for locked bootloader

Comment: The tutorial says that it will work even with locked bootloader, although I've unlocked the bootloader first.

Comment: i think it will work on .100 build LB and not on .400 build LB